# How can you get the Tweet you just Tweeted using iOS's libraries and TWRequest?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, twitter

I successfully tweet a message and in the result block successfully make a request to statuses/user_timeline.json and it returns my most recent tweets.  The problem is, the tweet I *just* made isn't in the result set, only older tweets.

How can I get the information for the tweet I *just* made using **TWTweetComposeView**?

Thanks

EDIT: For now I'm making a statuses/user_timeline.json (count=1) request before sending the tweet so I know the ID of the last tweet made, in the result block of TWTweetComposeView I then start making requests to statuses/user_timeline.json with since_id=*thepreviousid* until I get a result containing at least 1 tweet... lame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tweet using the `statuses/update.json` twitter API call, the tweet is returned in the response.

`-[TWRequest performRequestWithHandler]` will provide an NSData object that can be converted to NSString and then parsed to provide the details of the submitted tweet.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear before but I'm using TWTweetComposeView to make the request.  I also, elsewhere make requests using TWRequest directly and that works fine, you're right.

Comment: I'm just going to go ahead and mark this as the answer since you _can't_ get the info I want using TWTweetComposeView, you have to use TWRequest.